# release or not release

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I'm developing an iPhone application.

I have the following property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Point2D* endPoint;
```

And this is a method on the same class:

```
- (id)initWithX:(CGFloat)x Y:(CGFloat)y;
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        endPoint = [[Point2D alloc] initWithX:x Y:y];

    ...
}
```

And finally the dealloc method on the same class:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [endPoint release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

My question is it this code correct?

```
endPoint = [[Point2D alloc] initWithX:x Y:y];
```

Or maybe I have to do an autorelease here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment

`endPoint = [[Point2D alloc] initWithX:x Y:y];`

does not increase the retainCount, so if you want to keep endPoint to use later you don't use autorelease here.

Or you can use like this

`self.endPoint = [[[Point2D alloc] initWithX:x Y:y] autorelease];`

=> This assignment will increase the counter of endPoint.

Answer (score 5):

Go read the [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) as it'll explain all of this and a lot more.

In short, that code is correct.

If you did `self.endPoint = [... alloc/init ...]`, then you'd need to autorelease or release in `init` to balance the extra retain.

Answer (score 0):

change `endPoint = [[Point2D alloc] initWithX:x Y:y];` to

```
Point2D *temp = [[Point2D alloc] initWithX:x Y:y];
self.endPoint = temp;
[temp release];
```

to take advantage of the properties retaining setter.

Comment: That'll leak without a balancing release in there somewhere.

Comment: I'd go with just setting the ivar directly;  avoids any setter override madness.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use endPoint directly but rather through self.endPoint.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Point2D* endPoint;

- (id)initWithX:(CGFloat)x Y:(CGFloat)y;
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.endPoint = [[[Point2D alloc] initWithX:x Y:y] autorelease]; //It'll retain it for us.

    ...
}

- (void)dealloc {
    self.endPoint = nil; //setting it to nil means it'll release the object it was previously pointing to.
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Not really;  in init/dealloc there is a lot of reason to go directly to the ivar.

Comment: @bbum true but in this case it's best just to use the property.

Comment: No, it really isn't.  If the setter/getter has been overridden in a subclass, you are hosed.  If there is a setter/getter that has custom behavior, it'll be fired during initialization/deallocation, exactly when the object is in an undefined state.  Note no down vote -- it isn't *that* big of a deal, in practice, but there are definitely some traps to be aware of.